# Google Cloud Platform Service Account is Unable to Access Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I encounter the following warning:

> WARNING: You do not appear to have access to project [$PROJECT] or it does not exist.

after running the following commands locally:

1. Activate and set a service account:

   ```sh
   gcloud auth activate-service-account \
   $SERVICE_ACCOUNT \
   --key-file=key.json

   #=>

   Activated service account credentials for: [$SERVICE_ACCOUNT]
   ```
2. Select `$PROJECT` as the above service account:

   ```sh
   gcloud config set project $PROJECT

   #=>

   Updated property [core/project].
   WARNING: You do not appear to have access to project [$PROJECT] or it does not exist.
   ```

My own GCP account is associated with the following roles:

- App Engine Admin
- Cloud Build Editor
- Cloud Scheduler Admin
- Storage Object Creator
- Storage Object Viewer

Why is this service account unable to `set` `$PROJECT`?  Is there a role or permission I am missing?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing when attempting `gcloud config set project my-project`. The key I'm using worked fine yesterday and I've not made any IAM changes. I've also verified the Id of the key I'm using is what's specified in the Service Accounts listed in the console.

Comment: Worth noting that it's a warning, rather than an error. I can still use the key in question successfully, despite getting the warning you've detailed.

Does your key work when you interact with GCP after you get the warning?

Comment: @eversMcc is right. It ended up just being an error and it wasn't working because of an entirely different reason with my `gcloud app deploy` command.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe this is an erroneous warning message. I see the same warning message on my service account despite the fact that the account has permissions on my GCP project and can successfully perform necessary actions.

You might be seeing this error due to an unrelated problem. In my case, I was trying to deploy to AppEngine from a continuous integration environment (Circle CI), but I hadn't enabled the [App Engine Admin API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/appengine.googleapis.com/overview). Once I enabled the API, I was able to deploy successfully.

Comment: You are correct - It ended up just being an error and it wasn't working because of an entirely different reason with my gcloud app deploy command

Comment: Agreed and confirmed - this typically occurs when something is invalid and it just shows this weird generic error message. This can commonly occur when an environment var is invalid or missing.

Comment: For my case it turned out that I provided wrong project name.

Comment: Gah, this happened to me as well!  The error following this warning was the real problem.

Answer (score 65):

The solution to this issue might be to enable the Cloud Resource Manager API in your Google Cloud Console [here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/overview) by clicking enable.

Comment: This solution worked for me better than the chosen answer.

Comment: @bryan I think this is the correct answer.

Comment: correct answer!

Comment: For those wondering how you could find out by yourself it was the "Cloud Resource Manager API" that was not enabled, add the `--log-http` option to your gcloud command, which will give output the full HTTP error response, in my case, it gives: `"error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Cloud Resource Manager API has not been used in project... before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting..."`

Answer (score 17):

I encountered this error when I started out with Google CLoud Platform.

The issue was that I configured/set a non-existing project (`my-kube-project`)
as my default project using the command below:

```
gcloud config set project my-kube-project
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

I had to list my existing projects first:

```
gcloud projects list
```

And then I copied the ID of the project that I wanted, and ran the command again this time:

```
gcloud config set project gold-magpie-258213
```

And it worked fine.

**Note**: You cannot change the ID of a project's **ID** or **Number**,you can only change the **Name**.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 3):

I was encountering the same error when trying to deploy an app to Google App Engine via a service account configured in CircleCI and resolved it by having the following roles (permissions) attached to my service role:

- App Engine Deployer
- App Engine Service Admin
- Cloud Build Editor
- Storage Object Creator
- Storage Object Viewer

I also had the **App Engine Admin API** enabled, but *not* the **Cloud Resource Manager API**.

Answer (score 3):

The

> WARNING: You do not appear to have access to project [$PROJECT_ID] or it does not exist.

warning **will** appear if there isn't at least one role granted to the service account that contains the `resourcemanager.projects.get` permission.

In other words, the warning **will** appear if the result of the following commands is blank:

1. Gather all roles for a given `$SERVICE_ACCOUNT` (this works for **any** account, not just service accounts):

   ```sh
   gcloud projects get-iam-policy $PROJECT_ID \
   --flatten='bindings[].members' \
   --format='table(bindings.role)' \
   --filter="bindings.members:${SERVICE_ACCOUNT}"


   #=>

   ROLE
   . . .
   ```
2. For each `$ROLE` gathered above, either:

   ```sh
   gcloud iam roles describe $ROLE \
   --flatten='includedPermissions' \
   --format='value(includedPermissions)' \
   --project=$PROJECT_ID | grep \
   --regexp '^resourcemanager.projects.get$'
   ```

   if the `$ROLE` is a **custom** (`projects/$PROJECT_ID/roles/$ROLE`), or:

   ```sh
   gcloud iam roles describe roles/$ROLE \
   --flatten='includedPermissions' \
   --format='value(includedPermissions)' | grep \
   --regexp '^resourcemanager.projects.get$'
   ```

   if the `$ROLE` is a **curated** (`roles/$ROLE`).

**Note**: the difference between `gcloud` command formatting for custom and curated roles is what makes listing all permissions associated with all roles associated with a single account difficult.

If you have confirmed that **none** of the roles associated with a service account contain the `resourcemanager.projects.get` permission, then either:

- Update at least one of the custom roles associated with the service account with the `resourcemanager.projects.get` permission:

  ```sh
  gcloud iam roles update $ROLE \
  --add-permissions=resourcemanager.projects.get \
  --project=$PROJECT_ID

  #=>

  description: $ROLE_DESCRIPTION
  etag: . . .
  includedPermissions:
  . . .
  - resourcemanager.projects.get
  . . .
  name: projects/$PROJECT_ID/roles/$ROLE
  stage: . . .
  title: $ROLE_TITLE
  ```

  **Warning**: make sure to use the `--add-permissions` flag here when updating, as the `--permissions` flag will **remove** any other permissions the custom role used to have.
- Create a custom role:

  ```sh
  gcloud iam roles create $ROLE \
  --description="$ROLE_DESCRIPTION" \
  --permissions=resourcemanager.projects.get \
  --project=$PROJECT_ID \
  --title='$ROLE_TITLE'

  #=>

  Created role [$ROLE].
  description: $ROLE_DESCRIPTION
  etag: . . .
  includedPermissions:
  - resourcemanager.projects.get
  name: projects/$PROJECT_ID/roles/$ROLE
  stage: . . .
  title: $ROLE_TITLE
  ```

  and associate it with the service account:

  ```sh
  gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID \
  --member=serviceAccount:$SERVICE_ACCOUNT \
  --role=projects/$PROJECT_ID/roles/$ROLE

  #=>

  Updated IAM policy for project [$PROJECT_ID].
  auditConfigs:
  . . .
  ```
- Associate the service account with a curated role that already contains the `resourcemanager.projects.get` permission, which has been discussed above.

  If you want to know which curated roles already contain the `resourcemanager.projects.get` permission and don't want to craft a complex shell loop, it might be easier to go [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles) and filter all roles by `Permission:resourcemanager.projects.get`.

**Note**: if you are running into issues, be sure to read the requirements for granting access to resources [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access).

Comment: This should be the top and accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I received this error because I entered the project's name (e.g. sample-app) after `gcloud config set project` rather than the project's *ID*. These may be the same in some cases, but if you use a generic name (like sample-app), Google will probably assign some extra numbers to the name (e.g. sample-app-398022).

(To find your project's ID, go to https://console.cloud.google.com/welcome and select your project within the top dropdown menu. You'll then be taken to a 'Welcome' page that shows your project's name (e.g. sample-app) and its ID (e.g. sample-app-398021). The ID will also be shown below the project name when you first creating your project.)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a role that contains compute.projects.list.  The "viewer" kinds of roles are useful here or you can create a custom role tailored to your specific needs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).